FAILED Receive DLR in Kannel access .log
In my kannel i am able to see some of messages as "FAILED Receive DLR"
This is the below log for that. kannel access logs
2024-04-24 12:14:18 FAILED Receive DLR [SMSC:SMC_NAME] [SVC:] [ACT:] [BINF:] [FID:] [META:?smpp?network_error_code=%03%01%9D&] [from:+919355XXXXXX] [to:SENDER] [msg:114:id:XXXXX2406441XXXXX sub:001 dlvrd:001 submit date:240424121418 done date:240424121418 stat:REJECTD err:413 text:] [udh:0:]
Could you pleas help us to find the reason and any configuration needs to be set in kannel.
using local redis for dlr connection and pointing to gateway to fetch the message_id for the dlr

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
